Телеграм бот на Python byTelegramBorApi
Написал бота, простой гид по городу, который отправляет текст и изображения. Все файлы берёт с локального пк. Встал вопрос выгрузки на сервер. Попробывал Amvera, хоть и выгрузил все файлы разными способами, не видит этих фвайлов. Что в таком случае делать? Это проблема только этого сервера или так будет со всеми?

Как именно вы отсылаете файлы?
Через img = open('image.jpg', 'rb') и bot.send_photo(cid, img)? А вообще, советую загрузить изображения на какой-то обменник (тот же imgur), и уже отправлять их

А в чем проблема использовать рекомендованный способ телеграм передачи медиа по file_id? Один раз отправить боту, получить file_id и рассылай сколько угодно раз моментально. Не нужно их хранить у себя, нет нагрузки на сеть, пользователь не ждет, когда эти изображения бот загрузит (и будет грузить каждый раз)
